# How to get to which datacenter a network storage belongs to using SoftLayer Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, network-storage

I'm using:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage

to get a list of all network storages.

But, in http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage , I don't see a way to get the datacenter details to which the network storage belongs to.

But, 'slcli iscsi list' (for example) is showing 'datacenter' column.

How can I get the same via Ruby SoftLayer API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an object mask to get datacenter value

> e.g.:
>   **mask[serviceResource[datacenter[name]]]**

Also, you can try the following ruby script to get that kind of information

```
# Get Network Storage
#
# This script retrieves an account's associated storage volumes.
#
# Important manual pages
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage
#
# @License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
# @Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

# Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey 
SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

# Create the client
client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: SL_API_USERNAME, api_key: SL_API_KEY)

# Define an object mask to get datacenter name
object_mask = 'mask[serviceResource[datacenter[name]]]'

begin
  storages = client['SoftLayer_Account'].object_mask(object_mask).getNetworkStorage
  print "+------------+---------------------------+------------+-----------------------+\n"
  print "| ID         | Datacenter                | Size       |  Username             |\n"
  print "+------------+---------------------------+------------+-----------------------+\n"
  storages.each do |storage|
      printf('| %-10s ', storage['id'])
      if storage['serviceResource'].has_key?('datacenter')
          datacenter = storage['serviceResource']['datacenter']['name']
      else
          datacenter = 'None'
      end
      printf('| %-25s ', datacenter)
      printf('| %-10s ', storage['capacityGb'])
      printf("| %-21s | \n", storage['username'])
      end
  rescue StandardError => exception
  puts "Error. : #{exception}"
end
```

**References:**

- [Ruby SoftLayer](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Ruby)
- [Object Masks](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks)
- [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ruber. I could get the 'datacenter' details now. But one question, why are you checking for storage['serviceResource'].has_key?('datacenter') ?
Is there a possibility that storage exists without being assigned to any datacenter?

Comment: Well, for some snapshot items (few of them) the datacenter is not displayed using [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage) method, but you can use [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getServiceResource](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getServiceResource) method, to get the datacenter for them. This is a minor issue that we are working now to fix it. For that reason I added the validation for key **storage['serviceResource'].has_key?('datacenter')**.

Comment: My apologies if it affects your requirements.